# Sharepoint how to read array value from json query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sharepoint

All,

I like to retrieve the value of items in my d.data.results in SharePoint.
My code can handle text but when there is an array, like with a choice field, it does not return the value.

```
function writedata(x, txt) {    
    if (typeof txt === 'undefined' || txt === null) {
    console.log("undefined");    
    return undefined;
}
    console.log(txt);
    doc.setFontSize(sizes[0]);
    doc.text(x, varHeight, txt); 
};
```

The input for the function is d.data.fieldname
d.data.Frequency returns an array with [0] = "Once"

How can I get the value of this field:
I tried:

```
....
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) 
{  
     var item = d.data.Frequency[0].Title;  
         console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks for checking my spelling CK. You didn't want to answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing the following code.

```
function GetArraydataType(x, txt) {

            if (txt === 'undefined' || txt === null) {
               console.log("undefined");
            return;
            }
            var myOutput = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
            myOutput += txt[i] + ", ";
}
            doc.setFontSize(sizes[0]);
            doc.text(x, varHeight, myOutput.substr(0, myOutput.lastIndexOf(",")));
};
```